# Function key of HP laptop changing behaviour after waking up from sleep mode in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm in the process of setting up an Arch Linux system on an HP laptop, but because of the funky way the keyboard is laid oud (the key labeled as the less/greater key sends scancode 105, which is interpreted as right control by X) I have to try and setup my own keyboard configuration.
The thing is, when I went to use xev to see which keys send which scancodes, I noticed some oddities with the function keys.
As a precision, I use a French AZERTY layout, and the behaviours I am reporting have happened on all the French layouts I've loaded with `setxkbmap` (as in, the `fr` layout, with models `evdev` as well as all the ones beginning with `hp`).

- The first is that F1 has a really inconsistent behaviour.
  Just after booting and loging into the system, when the F1 key is pressed with no modifiers applied, it sends scancode 146, which is usually mapped to Help, so far so good. But further down the line, I'll notice that it doesn't do that anymore when pressed on it's own, but instead sends in succession the scancodes 133 (mapped to Super_L) and 67 (mapped to F1), and I don't know what triggers this change.
  A reboot allways reverts the key to it's expected behaviour.
- Secondly, the F4 key behaves in much the same way: after a reboot and when pressed on it's own, it sends 164 (XF86Favorites), but at some point it will change to sending 133 (Super_L) and 33 (p).
  This change seems to happen at the same time that the F1 key changes it's behaviour.
  According to [this](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/f4.htm#hp) page, on HP laptops, the F4 key is used to switch between the laptop display and external monitor.
- The final odd thing is that sometimes, and usually when modifier keys and function keys are pressed in quick succession, some scancode will be sent that I did not expect to be sent (like XF86Sleep) ; when methodically trying out each function key with each modifiers, these mysterious scancodes don't show up so I have no idea what they're about...
  This happens only very occasionally, and it's difficult to reproduce since I'm not really sure what are the conditions to reproduce it.

Does someone know what's going on ?
I'm relatively new to Linuxland and I've really tried to wrap my head around how X does keyboard configuration, but I'm still very confused so if there's something I'm misunderstanding, or if I'm doing something stupid, please enlighten me.
I also don't really know what kind of information would be usefull to provide, so tell me if you need something more to help me figure this out.

As an aside, the fn key also seems to act like a dead key, in the sense that when pressed and then released, the next time a function key is pressed will be as if the fn key was held down.
I find it a bit annoying but I've heard that the fn key is handled directly by the keyboard and not the OS, so I don't know if I can do anything about that.

**Edit 1:** So, immediately after posting this question, I continued to fiddle around with my keyboard and figured *something* out, which sheds some light but doesn't answer much.
The thing that causes F1 and F4 to change behaviour is when X goes to sleep.
After a fresh restart, putting X to sleep by folding the laptop close or pressing F5 (which sends to X the signal to go into sleep).
Before this, F1 and F4 behave as expected, and upon waking up they are messed up.
I fact, the F5 key is also changed by this, because after waking up, it doesn't sand any scancode when pressed on it's own according to xev.
This also explains why I was sometime seing keycodes I did not recognise.

But now that I know this, I've noticed strangeness with other F keys too.
Here is a compitation of what all the affected keys do when pressed their own, according to xev, before and after the change :

- F1 : Before = 146 (Help). After = 133 + 67 (Super_L + F1).
- F4 : Before = 164 (XF86Favorites). After = 133 + 33 (Super_L + p).
- F5 : Before = 150 (XF86Sleep). After = nothing
- F11 : Before = 136 + 171 (Cancel + XF86AudioNext). After = 171 (XF86AudioNext).
- F12 : Before = 255 + 171 (XF86RFKill + XF86AudioNext) or 171 + 255 (XF86AudioNext + XF86RFKill) without a discernable pattern. After = 255 (XF86RFKill) every time.

So some of them get messed up after waking from sleep, and some are messed up before but get fixed by going to sleep...
I am so confused.

Comment: What's the model of the laptop? When laptops are behaving funky in Linux, you can often get useful insights by searching for "<laptop-model> linux problems" or so

Comment: It's an HP 14s-fq0000nf. Quite a mouthful, but it's the actual model name. I've tried looking things up for this model specifically but not much of use has turned up.

Comment: All the search results are coming up in French. This makes me think you might be able to fix it by rejigging the locale. It's been a while since I installed Arch Linux, but iirc there were sections where you need to do locale and keyboard settings, you might want to check what options are in there for asserting that this machine follows France settings.

Comment: Hmm, touché. I haven't done much with the locales because I didn't really understood what they were about. I'll try setting them up properly and see if that does anything.

Comment: Well, I set all the locales to French (fr_FR.UTF-8 to be precise) and rebooted, but it didn't seem to change anything. Even after a full shutdown, nothing has changed.

Comment: You might also need to check what keyboards are on offer. I doubt it's US, which is the default.

Comment: Yes, the oddities I've reported were happening on the layouts loaded by running `setxkbmap -layout fr -variant nodeadkeys`, `setxkbmap -layout fr`, and `setxkbmap -model hp -layout fr`. I might do a more exhaustive search for a French layout that matches my physical keyboard and doesn't have the weirdness I described, but tomorrow as it's getting late where I am.

Comment: Just a thought: the function keys on laptops usually double as keys for adjusting things like screen brightness, secondary output, volume control, etc. The function keys are accessed by pressing a "fn" key simultaneously. Many modern laptops also offer a "fn lock" key, which swaps the behaviour so that  F1, F2, etc. can be typed without the "fn" key, and to use the special function you have to press the "fn" key. Maybe something causes your keyboard to switch modes?

Comment: Well, my laptop's keyboard doesn't have such a key, and the behaviour I'm experiencing is not what you're describing, so I doubt that my keyboard is going into fn-lock mode somehow. But something is definitely changing, so if it's not fn-locking, maybe it's changing to some other mode. But I don't know what that would be, and why it would be triggered when the computer goes into sleep mode.